# Is it possible (and relatively easy) for me to backup snaps, program data, and person files from Ubuntu 18.10 and 18.04?

Tags: backup

The question should be mostly self-explanatory, but essentially I want to be able to move snaps, programs, (and their data) personal files, and preferably system settings from Ubuntu 18.10 to Ubuntu 18.04.

Am I able to use a standard Linux backup software for this, would it be a manual thing, or is moving data from a newer to an older version not realistic?

Any input's greatly appreciated, I don't know Ubuntu so well. I made the switch from Windows about 2 months ago

Answer (score 0):

Snaps: Yes, but it's not worthwhile. Simply download the Snap again on the new system. All releases of Ubuntu use *exactly the same* Snaps. That's the point of Snaps.

Programs: NO - doing this with debs will BREAK YOUR SYSTEM HORRIBLY. Yes, you can do it from a Snap easily and safely.

Program Data: Yes, easily.

Personal Files: Yes, easily.

Since you don't know how to use backup software in Ubuntu, it's probably easier to simply move your files manually.